# How do the LIGO team arrive at the number of round trips in the laser arm etalon?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, experimental-technique, ligo

The quoted number of laser beam round trips in the arm cavity for LIGO on the MIT site is 280 times. How did they arrive such a number? Since the laser frequency is stabilized to less than 1 Hz, the coherence length is more than 3*10^8 meters, which will support 50,000 round trips before losing coherence.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the LIGO technical document](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4547) the LIGO optical cavities are designed to have a finess of 450, where [the finesse is defined as](https://www.rp-photonics.com/finesse.html):

$$ F = \frac{2\pi}{1 - \rho} $$

where $\rho$ is the fractional loss per round trip. A finesse of 450 corresponds to a loss of about 1.4% per round trip, so after 280 round trips the beam is reduced to about 2% of its original intensity.

The discussion of why a finesse of 450 was chosen is a little opaque. The document says only that it was chosen as a tradeoff between laser power and thermal noise.

Comment: The round trip losses in the LIGO arm are 44 ppm. I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: @RobJeffries the 44ppm may be the unwanted losses. On the arxiv paper p.14 you can find that the transmission of the ITM mirror is 1.4% which are "useful" losses of an optical resonator. The ETM mirror has 5ppm of transmission and the compensation plates outside of the cavity have transmissions of less than 50ppm.